# chroot with working directory specified

Tags: bash, shell, chroot, cd-command, cwd

Say I want to write wrapper for `chroot` command with the possibility to set working directory otherwise preserving `chroot` semantics. Thus semantics should be:

```
chroot.sh <chroot-dir> <working-dir> <command> [arg]...
```

My naive attempt is:

```
#!/bin/sh

chroot_dir=$1
working_dir=$2

shift 2

chroot "$chroot_dir" sh -c "cd $working_dir; $*"
```

But this fails to correctly handle:

```
chroot.sh /path/to/chroot /tmp touch 'filename with space'
```

I cannot figure out how it should be implemented correctly.
Is it possible using bash only?

On my CentOS 6 system `chroot` command doesn't support setting working directory. Probably this is not true on other systems.

Comment: You might have better luck with $@ instead of $*

Comment: Simply replacing $* in given example with $@ gives even more weird results.

Comment: Looks like on the last line, you want: `chroot "${chroot_dir}" sh -c ...`

Answer (score 3):

The way to handle this is to pass the arguments as a quoted list *after* the command invoked via `chroot`:

```
chroot "$chroot_dir" sh -c 'cd "$1" && shift && "$@"' - "$working_dir" "$@"
```

Here's a worked example, including the setup of a vanilla `chroot` environment.

Setup

```
# Where
chroot="$HOME/chroot"

# Directory structure
mkdir -p -m755 "$chroot"/{bin,dev,lib,tmp}
chmod 1777 "$chroot"/tmp

# Shell
cp -a /bin/dash "$chroot"/bin/sh

# Devices
cp -a /dev/{null,tty} "$chroot"/dev

# Libraries
cp -p $(ldd /bin/dash | sed 's/^.*=> //' | awk '!/vdso/ {print $1}' ) "$chroot"/lib/

# Demonstration executable
cat >"$chroot"/bin/args <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
#
echo "Got $# arg(s): $*"
echo "CWD: $(pwd)"
printf '> %s <\n' "$@"
EOF
chmod a+x "$chroot"/bin/args
```

Execution (of the application `args`)

```
working_dir=/tmp
chroot "$chroot" /bin/sh -c 'cd "$1" && shift && "$@"' - "$working_dir" args 'one two' three
```

Output

```
Got 2 arg(s): one two three
CWD: /tmp
> one two <
> three <
```

As you can see from the output, whitespace and arguments are preserved correctly.

Comment: This assumes a shell binary is available within the chroot, which may not be the case. Is there a way to do this without access to sh/bash in the chroot?

Comment: @AxelFontaine it assumes nothing in the chroot. My instructions include ensuring there's a shell inside the chroot by copying it in. If you want to set the working directory before invoking an executable you have to find some way of doing that. Write your own C program or use a shell. Either could work, and I chose the shell route

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've came to the following solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

chroot_dir=$1
working_dir=$2

shift 2

printf -v CMDS " %q" "$@"

chroot "$chroot_dir" sh -c "cd \"$working_dir\";$CMDS"
```

Answer (score -2):

This seem to do what you're after:

```
#!/bin/bash

chroot_dir="$1"
shift

working_dir="$1"
shift

cmd="$@"

chroot "${chroot_dir}" sh -c "cd ${working_dir} ; ${cmd}"
```

Note that /tmp start off with just the script:

```
# ls /tmp
chroot.sh
```

I have a chroot at `/mnt/foo`, which is a bind mount to `/`:

```
# /tmp/chroot.sh /mnt/foo /tmp touch '"filename with spaces"'
```

Now note that a file `filename with spaces` exists:

```
# ls -1 /tmp
chroot.sh
'filename with spaces'
```