# `chroot` bash not working after copying both the binary and its dependencies

Tags: security, root, chroot

I have reviewed the existing questions and responses but none worked in my case. So I'm opening a new question.

OS: Debian

Here are my steps:

First, copy `/bin/bash`:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mychroot/bin
$ sudo cp /bin/bash /mychroot/bin/
```

Then, find dependencies:

```
$ sudo ldd /bin/bash
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd807ec000)
    libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007f00c86fa000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f00c86f4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f00c8520000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f00c8869000)
```

Copy dynamically-linked dependencies. In case I copied into the wrong directories I tried them all:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /mychroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
$ sudo ldd /bin/bash | grep "=>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' sudo cp -v '{}' /mychroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2' -> '/mychroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'
```

```
# copy deps into lib64 (just in case)
$ sudo mkdir -p /mychroot/lib64
$ sudo ldd /bin/bash | grep "=>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' sudo cp -v '{}' /mychroot/lib64
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib64/libtinfo.so.6'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2' -> '/mychroot/lib64/libdl.so.2'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib64/libc.so.6'
```

```
# copy deps into lib (just in case)
$ sudo mkdir -p /mychroot/lib
$ sudo ldd /bin/bash | grep "=>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I '{}' sudo cp -v '{}' /mychroot/lib
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib/libtinfo.so.6'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2' -> '/mychroot/lib/libdl.so.2'
'/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' -> '/mychroot/lib/libc.so.6'
```

Run `chroot`:

```
$ sudo chroot /mychroot
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

---

Update: realized I needed to copy all the files now. Tried `sudo cp -r /lib /lib64 /mychroot` for a test and still not working.

Comment: Where did you copy `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to?

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda from my understanding, this file is statically linked so it was copied with the binary. I only copied the ones that were dynamically linked (e.g. the ones with `=>`)

Comment: It's the dynamic linker, so I thought it might be needed. I'm no Linux user, so I'm not turning that into an answer.  If you make it work, post an answer with the full solution.

Comment: Use the setup shown in [my answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/716801/100397), replacing my references to `dash` with `bash` for your purpose

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chroot with working directory specified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402099/chroot-with-working-directory-specified)

Comment: I followed roaima's answer up until `#Demonstration executable` but still get the same `failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory` error... still trying to understand more.

Comment: @yk3rt did you replace references to  `dash` (and `sh` as it happens) with `bash`? It works for me

Comment: So, @Kusalananda was right. It was the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` library that was missing. Turned out my cp command was a bit off and I copied it to `x86_64-linux-gnu` instead of `lib64`... Now that I updated the command to `cp --parent` and things worked.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` library that was missing. These shared libraries should also be in the correct directories as well.

Here's what worked for me eventually (changed where I was creating the chroot environment a bit but this is trivial):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/mychroot/{bin,lib,lib64}

$ cp /bin/bash ~/mychroot/bin/bash

$ ldd /bin/bash
linux-vdso.so.1
libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

$ cp --parent {/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6,/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2} ~/mychroot

$ sudo chroot ~/mychroot /bin/bash
```